# How to control the handle order of multiple coexisting VSTO Word Addins

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

If I have two different VSTO AddIns installed on the same Word application, is there a way to know which one of them first receives the events raised by Word. For example the DocumentOpen event?
Can I control that order?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find anything specific about event order in multiple add-ins (*but I believe I've read something about it years ago*) so I did simple test

I created three Excel add-ins with this code

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{           
  this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += Application_WorkbookBeforeSave;
}

void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Add-in 1");
}
```

One of them I gave it random name as I wanted to know if Excel runs them in alphabetical order, in one of the add-in I set the **Cancel = true**

I don't know why but Excel always fired the **ExcelAddin 2** first, then **ExcelAddin 1** and finished with **AAExcelAddin**. I tried to rebuild (*I also cleaned my solutions first*) in different order but the order was still the same (*note the very first addin created was the ExcelAddin 1*) No matter if I run it from VS or just simply start Excel and pressed CTRL+S

Based on above I would say that you should not have any logic in your code that assume certain order of add-ins. You never know if any new add-in will break the order.

Also keep in mind that if you use any of the cancellation events (*has the argument Cancel*) and you cancel it (*Cancel=true*) then all the other add-ins will receive the event and will still run it but the Cancel flag will be set to true from the previous one.

In my case I set Cancel=true in the add-in that was fired at first (*ExcelAddin 2*) and even the two other add-ins received the event, they didn't save as saving was cancelled in the first one.

Comment: Wow thanks for the elaborate test. I suspected what you said. I wonder why none of this is documented. It would be nice to know what we can expect.